# Is this a mistake specifying dimensions in the IFAB laws?

Tags: rules, football

> the technical area should only extend 1 m (1 yd) on either side of the designated seated area and up to a distance of 1 m (1 yd) from the touchline

[Read Law 1.9](http://www.theifab.com/laws/the-field-of-play/chapters/the-technical-area)

Notice it mentions 1 meter and 1 yard **both**. Clearly, 1 yard = 0.9144 meters and they both are not equal. So, by writing "(1 yd)" in parentheses, what are the laws trying to indicate?

Comment: They rounded those (like the corner arcs and pitch dimension) to avoid decimals wherever possible. Only parts of the pitch where the exact size is essential (like goals and penalty box) haven't been rounded. If I can find a proper source I'll convert this to an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not a mistake. From Wikipedia article "[Football pitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Football_pitch)":

> Due to the original formulation of the Laws in England and the early supremacy of the four British football associations within IFAB, the standard dimensions of a football pitch were originally expressed in imperial units. **The Laws now express dimensions with approximate metric equivalents (followed by traditional units in brackets)**, but use of the imperial units remains common in some countries, especially in the United Kingdom.

So, 1 yard = 0.9144 meter ≈ 1 meter

From [IFAB 1974 minutes of the annual general meeting](http://static-3eb8.kxcdn.com/documents/466/132754_131217_1974min.pdf):

[image: decision]

I am not exactly sure when board approved this table of measurement as some meeting files are not available online.